# SQL Server update trigger with no primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a table with no primary key.  **This is beyond my control and I can't change it.**

I need to add a trigger that updates one column on an update.  Is there a way with no primary key?

If need to do:

```
update myTable
set someField = someValue
where myTable.pkID = inserted.pdID
```

However, I don't have a primary key so I don't know how to do the where clause.

Comment: Is there any column or combination of columns which is unique?

Comment: There may be a way depending on the how the updates are performed.  Do you expect a WHERE clause to be used in the updates?   Is there a limit to the column(s) that might be used in the WHERE clause?

Comment: There are temporary tables that get created.  Maybe this can do what you need.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/

Comment: If you don't have a primary key (nor any identifiable key) then you don't really have information worth storing. You have random facts (some would call it trivia).

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have a formal primary key per se, but you need some combination of values to identify the record(s) affected-- even if that is every column in the table:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET someField = someValue
FROM myTable INNER JOIN inserted ON
    myTable.[col1] = inserted.[col1] 
    AND myTable.[col2] = inserted.[col2]
    AND myTable.[col3] = inserted.[col3]
    --etc
```

If you don't have some combination of values that is unique, I'm afraid you'd be out of luck with this approach.